# What is a good clustering fitness metric for DBSCAN?

Tags: clustering, dbscan

Usually, my go-to goodness of fit for evaluating clustering (e.g., k-means) is the average silhouette.

However, for DBSCAN it doesn't work since there are lots of non-clustered points.  So increasing the stringency of the parameters removes neighboring clusters, and therefore increases the difference between intra- and inter-cluster distance -- just because there are less points clustered.

What is a good clustering method for DBSCAN that takes into account this issue or is robust to number of points clusters?

Comment: how about treating each non-clustered point as a single cluster?

Answer (score 2):

The only measure that I know that takes noise points and density into account is DBCV:

> Moulavi, D., Jaskowiak, P. A., Campello, R. J., Zimek, A., & Sander, J. (2014, April). Density-based clustering validation. In Proceedings of the 2014 SIAM International Conference on Data Mining (pp. 839-847). Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.

I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 1):

@thc there is another paper worth looking,

> Jaskowiak, P.A., 2015. On the evaluation of clustering results:
>   measures, ensembles, and gene expression data analysis (Doctoral
>   dissertation, Universidade de São Paulo).

It discusses in detail the validation of density based clustering methods including the `DBCV` suggested earlier. It also includes a rich discussion on related works and experimental evaluation.